# Removing ambiguity in bison

Tags: parsing, bison, context-free-grammar, flex-lexer, ambiguity

I am writing a simple parser in bison. The parser checks whether a program has any syntax errors with respect to my following grammar:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror (const char *s) /* Called by yyparse on error */
{
    printf ("%s\n", s);
}
%}
%token tNUM tINT tREAL tIDENT tINTTYPE tREALTYPE tINTMATRIXTYPE 
%token tREALMATRIXTYPE tINTVECTORTYPE tREALVECTORTYPE tTRANSPOSE
%token tIF tENDIF tDOTPROD tEQ tNE tGTE tLTE tGT tLT tOR tAND
%left "(" ")" "[" "]"
%left "<" "<=" ">" ">="
%right "="
%left "+" "-"
%left "*" "/"
%left "||"
%left "&&"
%left "==" "!="

%% /* Grammar rules and actions follow */
prog: stmtlst ;
stmtlst: stmt | stmt stmtlst ;
stmt: decl | asgn | if;
decl: type vars "=" expr ";" ;
type: tINTTYPE | tINTVECTORTYPE  | tINTMATRIXTYPE | tREALTYPE | tREALVECTORTYPE 
      | tREALMATRIXTYPE ;
vars: tIDENT | tIDENT "," vars ;
asgn: tIDENT "=" expr ";" ;
if: tIF "(" bool ")" stmtlst tENDIF ;
expr: tIDENT | tINT | tREAL | vectorLit | matrixLit | expr "+" expr| expr "-" expr
  | expr "*" expr | expr "/" expr| expr tDOTPROD expr | transpose ;
transpose: tTRANSPOSE "(" expr ")" ;
vectorLit: "[" row "]" ;
matrixLit: "[" row ";" rows "]" ;
row: value | value "," row ;
rows: row  | row ";" rows ; 
value: tINT | tREAL | tIDENT ;
bool: comp | bool tAND bool | bool tOR bool ;
comp: expr relation expr ;
relation: tGT | tLT | tGTE | tLTE | tNE | tEQ ;
%%
int main ()
{    
    if (yyparse()) {
        // parse error
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        // successful parsing
        printf("OK\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The code may look long and complicated, but i think what i am going to ask does not need the full code, but in any case i preferred to write the code. I am sure my grammar is correct, but ambiguous. When i try to create the executable of the program by writing "bison -d filename.y", i get an error saying that **conflicts: 13 shift/reduce**. I defined the precedence of the operators at the beginning of this file, and i tried a lot of combinations of these precedences, but i still get this error. How can i remove this ambiguity? Thank you

Comment: Can you list the shift/reduce errors?

Comment: it just says conflicts: 13 shift/reduce

Comment: run `bison --report=state filename.y`; it'll produce a .output file which lists all the states/conflicts

Comment: thanks, but are you sure? i run that command in the terminal and it still just says conflicts: 13 shift/reduce

Comment: the detailed output will be in a file (filename.output), not printed in the terminal

Comment: ok, thanks, i am looking at it now and will write here also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25922/discussion-between-valtron-and-bigo)

Comment: actually, it is a very long file and at the beginning it says Terminals which are not used

   tNUM
   "<"
   "<="
   ">"
   ">="
   "||"
   "&&"
   "=="
   "!="


State 64 conflicts: 5 shift/reduce
State 65 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 66 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 67 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 68 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 70 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
State 71 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce

Comment: FWIW, I've never found bison (or yacc) detailed output to be that helpful; it produces lots of info, but always in terms of things too alien to my input for me to determine what to do about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tOR`, `tAND`, and `tDOTPROD` need to have their precedence specified as well.